# How to store button value by pushing only once

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make a program that stores my button digital input so that I don't have to keep holding the button for it to work.

The algorithm I am trying to develop is when the button is pressed, it it executes the servoMomvement() function then increments count by one. If count is even then program runs, but then if the button is pressed again it will not be even and would stop working.

```
void loop() {


  while(true){
   int count = 0;
   bool isEven = count%2;
    bool condition = digitalRead(4);
    if(condition == true && isEven == false){
        servoMovement();
        count++;
      }
  }
}
```

It is not working as intended. I still have to hold to push button for it to not stop executing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer to incremenet count by one.This timer function check periodically button. And when you press it will work as you want. But first of all you have to know timers ability and capacity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the loop method is executed in a loop (like one could guess by the name of the method...) and therefore it's checked in every loop whether the button is pressed.

Because in your if statement it says `condition == true && ...` this will only be true if the condition is true (the button is pressed).

If I understood your question correctly you want to have some kind of start-/stop-button. If so you could try like this:

```
//global variable run
bool run;

void setup() {
  run = false;
}

void loop() {

  while(true){

    bool condition = digitalRead(4);
    if (condition) {
      run = !run;//switch the state of the run variable
      delay(50);//some delay to debounce the button; see https://www.brainy-bits.com/arduino-switch-debounce/ for more information
    }

    if(run){
      servoMovement();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a quite simple solution for that.
You can compare the actual buttonstate with the buttonstate the "round" before.

```
bool Button = false;
bool ButtonBefore = false;
bool help = false;
void loop()
{
   Button = digitalRead(ButtonPin);
   if(Button > ButtonBefore) help = !help;
   if(help) { do stuff; }
   ButtonBefore = Button;
}
```

When you press the button, "Button" becomes true while "ButtonBefore" is still false. So "Button" is bigger than "ButtonBefore" so "help" changes to true. In the next cycle "ButtonBefore" is even to "Button" so "help" won't change its state. When the button is released, "ButtonBefore" is bigger than "Button" so it "help" won't change too. So the state from "help" is changed when the button is pressed. 
I hope I could help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the code and it works. It can hold the value 1 but when I press the button again it does not stop the function.

Comment: Check if you have written this line "ButtonBefore = Button". You could also try to add a else after if(help). Sometimes else is needed to stop a function.